# Locate intersection between the floor and user's feet

Tags: python, opencv, logic, mediapipe

I am using `MediaPipe Pose` to track a person's jump height by calculating the person's time in air.

The jump starts when the user's foot index leaves the floor (photo included to show foot index #31 and #32). To measure the time in air I need to to find the exact point where the person's foot index leaves the floor and when the foot index returns to the floor.

[image]

At first I tried using the Y index of the foot index location, but the location of the Y index will change before the jump (in my definition) starts.
My second idea was to detect the floor itself and then pinpoint the intersection between the foot index and the floor. I am unable to find a library/open source that can achieve that.

Open to any suggestions.